# Excel Line drawing character formatting to remove gaps

Tags: excel, formatting

I have some code which draws a tree network in Excel Cells, using the Unicode characters shown in the Char Map...
[image: Char Map box line characters]

It all works okay except I get gaps between the characters as shown below

I have increased the point size to 16 - which makes the rows height automatically resize (increase) , but then I re-reduced the row height and reduced the gaps - but I can't seem to get rid of them. Has anyone else found and fixed this?
It does print with the gaps as well.

[image: Excel cells with gaps]

I have tried a few things based on Notpad++ being able to do this

1. Just one column Horizontally - done by concatenating the cells into a single cell The Vertical lines are gone

[image: Only one horizontal cell]

2. Merged Vertical and horizontally - Merged the cells vertically so just one very large cell this gives larger gaps

[image: Single Merged cell]

3. Inserting a TextBox   - still has the horizontal grid lines

[image: TextBox]

Test code -

1. put into a cell '=ExampleBoxes(1)'
2. see code for what the argument does Use argments 1,0,2
3. Put the code in a module and you will get the pictures

[image: What you get]

```
 Option Explicit

Function ExampleBoxes(arg As Integer) As String()
        Dim tst(1 To 5, 1 To 5)  As String ' Multiple Rows and Columns
        Dim tstbc(0 To 3, 0 To 3)  As String ' Multiple Rows and Columns
        Dim tstbc2(0 To 3, 0 To 3)  As String ' Multiple Rows and Columns
        Dim rc(1 To 5, 1 To 5)  As String ' Multiple Rows and Columns
        Dim rc0(1 To 5, 0) As String ' Multiple Rows
        Dim r0c0(0) As String ' One big cell merged over rows
        
        rc(1, 1) = GetBoxChar(1, 1)
        rc(1, 2) = GetBoxChar(1, 2)
        rc(1, 3) = GetBoxChar(1, 3)
        rc(1, 4) = GetBoxChar(0, 1)
        'rc(1, 5) = GetBoxChar(1, 3)
        
        rc(2, 1) = GetBoxChar(2, 1)
        rc(2, 2) = GetBoxChar(2, 2)
        rc(2, 3) = GetBoxChar(2, 3)
        rc(2, 4) = GetBoxChar(0, 1)
        'rc(2, 5) = GetBoxChar(1, 3)
        
        rc(3, 1) = GetBoxChar(3, 1)
        rc(3, 2) = GetBoxChar(3, 2)
        rc(3, 3) = GetBoxChar(3, 3)
        rc(3, 4) = GetBoxChar(0, 1)
        'rc(3, 5) = GetBoxChar(1, 3)
        
        rc(4, 1) = GetBoxChar(2, 1)
        rc(4, 2) = GetBoxChar(0, 2)
        rc(4, 3) = GetBoxChar(0, 2)
        rc(4, 4) = GetBoxChar(3, 3)
        'rc(4, 5) = GetBoxChar(1, 3)
        
        rc(5, 1) = GetBoxChar(3, 2)
        'rc(5, 2) = GetBoxChar(1, 3)
        'rc(5, 3) = GetBoxChar(1, 3)
        'rc(5, 4) = GetBoxChar(1, 3)
        'rc(5, 5) = GetBoxChar(1, 3)
        Dim clno As Integer, rwno As Integer
        For clno = 0 To 3
            For rwno = 0 To 3
                tstbc(clno, rwno) = GetBoxChar(clno, rwno)
                tstbc2(clno, rwno) = clno & "-" & rwno
            Next
        Next
    
        For clno = 1 To 5
            For rwno = 1 To 5
                If rc(rwno, clno) = "" Then rc(rwno, clno) = " "  ' To put the spaces in if we copy into notepad
                rc0(rwno, 0) = rc0(rwno, 0) & rc(rwno, clno) ' concatenate the columns into one line
                r0c0(0) = r0c0(0) & rc(clno, rwno) ' concatenate the columns into one line and rows into one cell
                tst(rwno, clno) = rwno & "-" & clno
            Next
            r0c0(0) = r0c0(0) & vbLf
        Next
    ' change totest each tyoe
    Select Case arg
        Case 0
        ExampleBoxes = rc
        Case 1
        ExampleBoxes = rc0
        Case 2
        ExampleBoxes = r0c0
        Case 3
        ExampleBoxes = tst
        Case 4
        ExampleBoxes = tstbc
        Case 5
        ExampleBoxes = tstbc2
    
    End Select
        'doboxes = strrc
        'doboxes = rc2
    
    End Function
    
    Function GetBoxChar(i As Integer, J As Integer) As String
        
        Dim boxChars(3, 3) As Long
        boxChars(0, 1) = 9474 'UD
        boxChars(0, 2) = &H2500 'LR
        
        boxChars(1, 1) = 9484 'TL
        boxChars(1, 2) = 9516 'TM
        boxChars(1, 3) = &H2510 'TR
    
        boxChars(2, 1) = 9500 'ML
        boxChars(2, 2) = 9532 'MM
        boxChars(2, 3) = 9508 'BL
    
        boxChars(3, 1) = 9492 'BL
        boxChars(3, 2) = 9524 'BM
        boxChars(3, 3) = &H2518 'BR
        GetBoxChar = ChrW(boxChars(i, J))
    
    End Function
```

Comment: I know this does not answer your question, but you could perhaps copy and paste the diagram into notepad in order to print without the gaps.

Comment: I didn't think of that - if anyone tries - each cell must have a space and you need to search and replace all tabs with nothing  . But I have a lot of other data , with some fancy formats to print as well in other cells - so it doesnt really work for me

Comment: What you suggested works in Notepad++ - but trying to insert a single TextBox in excel for the picture still has the white horizontal lines , the vertical lines disappear

Comment: Looks like the borders around each cell...

Comment: Can I see your code? I would liek to try something before I comment?

Comment: Indeed I think it is the border - Attempting to merge however made it worse

Comment: @Siddharth  I'm happy to share the code... but its not easy to separate out as a standalone part as there's a lot of stuff happening with other data  to actually draw the tree - The best I can do is just provide the final data which is put the cells

Comment: Since you want to print it, why not output the data to MS Word rather than Excel or Notepadd++. It will be much more easier...

Comment: Let me know if you want an example